# Java Help: Determining if Digits Can Form a Sequence

Tags: java, methods, int, boolean

I have a quick question on an assignment I'm trying to finish up. I'm writing a boolean method that takes three digit parameters (0-9) and returns true if they can be re arranged to make up a sequence. The hard part, for me at least, is that 0 can make a sequence with 8, 9, or 1,2. The three numbers are assumed to all be different. To be clear, the number 5,7,6 would be true because it can be rearranged to be 5, 6, 7, a sequence. Also 8,0,9 would return true, but 2,4,7 would not. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this, any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: Without knowing what you've done so far, it's impossible to "point you in the right direction".

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check the validity of two tests:

1. Are all numbers different?
2. Is the absolute difference between the extremes 2?

This would give you the following method:

```
public static boolean isSequence(int a, int b, int c) {
    if(a == 0) a = 10;
    if(b == 0) b = 10;
    if(c == 0) c = 10;
    //Add the commented-out lines to make it safe to use with non-different numbers.
    //boolean allDifferent = !(a == b) && !(b == c) && !(a == c);
    boolean extremesIsTwo = Math.abs(Math.max(Math.max(a, b), c)
        - Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c)) == 2;
    //return allDifferent && extremesIsTwo;
    return extremesIsTwo;
}
```

When you look at it, it's only a matter of simple logic, and finding the shortest path to the answer. There might be more optimized ways to do this, but this is clear, readable and works just fine.

Now, if you really want to get grinding on a problem of the like, you could either try to optimize this algorithm, or find another way to check that the three numbers are a sequence.

**EDIT** This version is scalable. And even though your requirements are for three arguments, I would still consider this solution, because it uses OOP to avoid repetition of code. As requested, it also doesn't check for duplicates.

```
public static boolean isSequenceScalable(List<Integer> list) {
    list = list.stream().map(i -> i = (i == 0) ? 10 : i).collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.sort(Integer::compareTo);
    if (Math.abs(list.get(0) - list.get(list.size() - 1)) == 2) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I'm running this method if and only if the numbers are all different. So yes, they are all assumed to be different by the time they get to this method. Also, what if I have the numbers 9,8,0? the extremes are 9 and 0, so the difference between them is 9, but the boolean extremesIsTwo would be false since none of the conditions would be true for those three numbers. I'm trying to figure out a way to include 0 as a possible member of a sequence with either 1,2 or 8,9

Comment: @JBarron Then all you have is not check for `allDifferent`, and return the value of `extremesIsTwo`. You can even inline the declaration of `extremesIsTwo` with the `return` statement (`return Math.abs(a - b)`...)

Comment: Oh, I did not realize you considered 9 and 0 to be contiguous. I'll get back to you!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Not exactly what I needed, but you made my life much easier sir!

Comment: @JBarron FYI, I just updated my answer with a scalable version that's more convenient than the first one.